# Согласование и семантика глаголов нсв и св

Tags: семантика

Сразу обозначу главную проблему.

1. Работа, помогающая достигать цели
2. Работа, помогающая достигнуть цели
3. Работа, способствующая достижению цели

Имеются варианты, моя задача - выбрать из них наиболее подходящий моим требованиям: учесть в предложении и процесс достижения, и само достижение цели как таковое. Насколько я понимаю, в первом варианте акцент смещён на процесс, а во втором - на результат. В таком случае есть ли сбалансированный вариант по типу "достигать и достигнуть цели " сразу в одном предложении? Если так и написать, то не будет ли такое доп. уточнение излишним? И хотя в предложении номер 3 слово "достижение" несёт сразу в себе два смысла: процесс и результат, мне кажется, доминирующим смыслом в "достижение" является результат, а уж потом процесс. Как тогда быть, если я хочу учесть равноценно оба значения. Может где-нибудь у меня вообще ошибка и написано не по правилам русского? Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.